# Need help finding a specific directory printing program

Tags: windows, printing, file-search, scripting, directories

I used to have this program that would print a list of folders into a txt document like so (little lines included):

```
01 Recipes
├───Cookies
│   ├───Christmas
│   │   ├───Red
│   │   └───Green
│   └───Halloween
└───Pizza
Food
├───Apples
├───Bananas
├───Coconuts
└───Seaweed
```

But I'm looking all over and can't find this program anywhere on the internet. To make it harder, few of these program advertise what their output will look like so I have to manually test each one, one at a time. If anyone remembers what this program was called, or knows of an alternative that does indentation for each level that would save me A LOT of trouble.

Comment: That looks a lot like the [tree view in FAR Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CP3K.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows, the command windows (cmd.exe) will provide you with a similar/useful command, known as tree.

[image]

You can direct the output to a text file using the > character.

The command syntax is:

```
tree /a /f > filename.txt
```

The /a will not give you the little lines, but removing it will do so. The /f switch displays all folders below the current location.

```
Folder PATH listing for volume USERS
Volume serial number is A649-5168
E:.
|   howto.txt
|   
\---Mangler
    |   make.sh
    |   
    \---src
            Mangler.java
```

If you direct to a file, the omission of the switch /a will result in non-ascii characters.

```
Folder PATH listing for volume USERS
Volume serial number is A649-5168
E:.
³   howto.txt
³   
ÀÄÄÄMangler
    ³   make.sh
    ³   
    ÀÄÄÄsrc
            Mangler.java
```